# how to calculate total for each enum of a field in aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregate

hello  I have this function where I want to calculate the number of orders for each status in one array, the code is

```
    let statusEnum = ["pending", "canceled", "completed"];
  let userOrders = await Orders.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [
          { senderId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id) },
          { driverId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id) },
          { reciverId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id) },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        totalOrders: { $sum: 1 },
        totalPendingOrders: "??", //I want to determine this for each order status
        totalCompletedOrders: "??",
        totalCanceledOrders: "??",
      },
    },
  ]);
```

so I could add add a $match and use {status : "pending"} but this will filter only the pending orders, I could also map the status enum and replace each element instead of the "pending" above and then push each iteration in another array , but that just seems so messy, is there any other way to calculate total for each order status with using only one aggregate?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group as you used, but with condition

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalPendingOrders: {
        $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$status", "pending" ] }, 1, 0 ] }
        },
      totalCompletedOrders: {
        $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$status", "completed" ] }, 1, 0 ] }
        },
      totalCanceledOrders: {
        $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$status", "canceled" ] }, 1, 0 ] }
        }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/evs5Ewtkk2n)**

Comment: Thank you that works, I also found this , its kinda shorter,  $group: {
        _id: "$status",
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        totalPrice: { $sum: "$price" },
      },   
    it calculates for all the available status and it works :)